# Пул подключений к базе данных

Tags: postgresql, rust, actix-web, connection-pool

Я начинающий программист на Rust. В данный момент работаю над сервисом который будет очень часто связываться с базой данных. Как я узнал, если на сервис оказывается высокая нагрузка, то в таких случаях стоит создавать пул подключений. В ютубе ничего внятного я не смог найти. На сайтах тоже не очень понятно как можно применить пул на практике. Может кто-нибудь подсказать, что такое пул подключений и из чего состоит логика этой структуры. Буду очень признателен.

Знаю про библиотеки r2d2-postgres и deadpool-postgres, какая из этих библиотек будет лучше?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.ru/book/ch20-02-multithreaded.html